# Characters rendered incorrectly in HttpEntity response

Tags: android, utf-8, character-encoding, http-post, httpresponse

I'm doing little app that receives some XML with UTF-8 encoding, the very same XML in browser renders characters correctly whereas in Android I've got some "Garbage" eg. WÅochy instead of Włochy or DwÃ³jka instead of Dwójka. Apparently I'm doing something wrong, can anyone help me figuring it out?

Best regards

```
String response = EntityUtils.toString( resEntity ).trim();
Log.i( CLASS_NAME, "RESPONSE=" + response );
//This returns response with incorrectly rendered characters eg. WÅochy instead of Włochy
```

Following is the code that sends POST request and receives response, it is run in AsyncTask:

```
protected Document doInBackground(ServiceQuery... queries)
{
    if ( m_sGateway == null ) return null;

    Document result = null;

    try
    {
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();

        HttpPost post = new HttpPost( m_sGateway );

        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        params.add( new BasicNameValuePair( "mdsXML", queries[0].getQueryString() ) );

        UrlEncodedFormEntity ent = new UrlEncodedFormEntity( params, HTTP.UTF_8 );
        post.setEntity( ent );
        HttpResponse responsePOST = client.execute( post );

        HttpEntity resEntity = responsePOST.getEntity();

        if ( resEntity != null )
        {
            Log.i( CLASS_NAME, "contentLength:" + resEntity.getContentLength() );
            Log.i( CLASS_NAME, "getContentEncoding():" + resEntity.getContentEncoding() );
            Log.i( CLASS_NAME, "getContentEncoding().isChunked():" + resEntity.isChunked() );
            Log.i( CLASS_NAME, "getContentEncoding().isRepeatable():" + resEntity.isRepeatable() );

            String response = EntityUtils.toString( resEntity ).trim();

            Log.i( CLASS_NAME, "RESPONSE=" + response );//This returns response with incorrectly rendered characters eg. WÅochy instead of Włochy


            DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();

            InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream( response.getBytes(HTTP.UTF_8) );


            result = db.parse( is );
            result.getDocumentElement().normalize();
        }

    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.e( CLASS_NAME, "doInBackground error." );
        result = null;
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: Check that the response coming back includes a character encoding, *and* that the response actually is encoded using that encoding. If that seems fine, then try forcing EntityUtils to use UTF-8 - http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/util/EntityUtils.html#toString(org.apache.http.HttpEntity,%20java.lang.String).

Comment: I will check it, the response XML has the UTF-8 encoding in processing instruction <?xml encoding="UTF-8" ?>, also the same service run from browser displays characters correctly.

Comment: Hi Paul, it helped, When I did:
    `Log.i(CLASS_NAME, "getContentCharSet="+EntityUtils.getContentCharSet( resEntity ));`
it returned null, then I have retrieved the string from entity using:
    `String response = EntityUtils.toString( resEntity, HTTP.UTF_8 ).trim();`
and my accents start to show correctly:) the trim was used only because I had some white characters before PI.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

credits for an answer to my problem goes to Paul Grime.

```
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;

String response = EntityUtils.toString( resEntity, HTTP.UTF_8 );
```

where resEntity is HttpEntity instance.