# Parsing French text with simple-Framework not working

Tags: android, character-encoding, xml-parsing, xml-serialization, simple-framework

I'm using simpleFramework for parsing an xml file in my android app.
My problem is in parsing french text like lets say this tag

```
<TagName>écrite</TagName>
```

The result I will receive when parsing is something like this "Ã©crite"
This is encoding (french) problem in the simpleFramework xml.
How can avoid that and have my text "écrite"

the xml header has utf8 :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

Comment: can you provide the xml header for your file ? i think that you have to use ISO encode.

Comment: post some code. this clearly shows an utf8 text (makes sense given it is xml) read using iso-8859-1 (or someting close) encoding

Comment: This is not an issue with SimpleFramework its your input stream or reader, it should be UTF-8. Also, make sure your XML file is also UTF-8. They must be like for like.

Comment: yeah you are right about that @ng. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have hit this issue before whilst using a SAX parser. When reading the file with a Java `InputStream` you need to specify the encoding of the stream in code- perhaps by reading the first line of the file as you have shown. Here is the code for assigning the encoding;

```
SAXParserFactory saxParserFactory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();     
final SAXParser saxParser = saxParserFactory.newSAXParser();
// Note the encoding on the reader...
final Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(<your file stream>, "UTF-8");       
final InputSource inputSource = new InputSource(reader);        
inputSource.setEncoding("UTF-8");
saxParser.parse(inputSource, <some handler>);
```

Hope that helps. If not- post back with how you are reading the XML file.

Comment: what was needed I use simple-framework but the problem wasn't in the parser as you said the problem is in changing the stream and not loosing the encoding
I found my solution here actually : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7464579/characters-rendered-incorrectly-in-httpentity-response